# button.Onclick event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=InsertBtn.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            var respond = confirm("Press ok if you confirm");

            if (respond == true) {
                this.onclick = true;
            } else {
                this.onclick = false
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Button ID="InsertBtn" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="InsertBtn_Click" />
```

how can I disable the `onclick` event when user response false?

Answer (score 0):

well, i found an answer from internet,

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#<%=InsertBtn.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {                                
                            var respond = confirm("Press ok if you confirm");

                            if (respond != true) {                    
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>

                <asp:Button ID="InsertBtn" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="InsertBtn_Click" />
```

by using the preventDefault() to cancel the onclick default action